# Отправка альбома в Telegram боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, media

Есть метод, который отправляет альбом из фото, но необходимо, чтоб он отправлял и **.jpg** and **.mp4** в соответствующих форматах в сообщениях. Сейчас метод отправляет, но вместо видео в сообщении фото т.к. в методе используется `InputMediaPhoto()`, не знаю, как обойти это.

```
def RequestMedia(username, list_of_media):
    pic = []
    media = []
    for pic_ in list_of_media:
        pic.append(open(str(pic_), "rb"))
    media.append(InputMediaPhoto(pic[0], caption=str(username)))
    pic.pop(0)
    try:
        for media_ in pic:
            media.append(InputMediaPhoto(media_))
        print(media)
        return media
    except:
        print(username + " имеет только одно фото!")
    return media
```

```
bot.send_media_group(555555555, RequestMedia(username, stories.GetStories(username, getID(username))))
```

Comment: совместить с `types.InputMediaVideo`?

Comment: @Violet такого нет

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/5b942a5b311719dbe8608316f3ca5fd050fdb3c1/tests/test_telebot.py#L518